# Quantum and Paraconsistent Logics

Tags: logic, physics, foundations

Is there any relation between these two logics? I know both are completely different "from construction", but recently I've read that paraconsistent logics tries to explain some things in quantum mechanics, mainly the superposition principle. Thanks!

Comment: Since paraconsistent logics are non-explosive (B doesn't follow from A and not A, for all A, B), they provide a more adequate basis for quantum logic than classical propositional logic. Look at Chapter 13 of [this](http://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0101028v2.pdf) article; it's on "Paraconsistent quantum logic".